# How do I enter line breaks in HTML link titles?

Tags: php

**PHP code:**

```
foreach( )
{
    if()
    {
        $title = $title . $sub['TITLE']."<br />";
    }
} 
echo '<a title="$title"> </a>';
```

when I place the cursor in anchor tag, the title should show one by one

```
i.e  A
     b
     c
```

but it showing now as

```
A <br />
B <br />
C <br />
```

Why the break tag showing here??

and also I need to know how to remove `<br/>` i.e only the last `<br/>` tag in the string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `title` tooltip does not respected HTML. Use `"\n"` instead.

Comment: oh thanx man,how to remove "\n" ,i.e the last "\n" in a variable

Comment: +1 also you'd probably need to escape the brackets (i.e. `&lt;br /&gt;`) to properly include the HTML anyway. You might want to use a JavaScript tooltip library if you need something more complex.

Comment: `@shanmugavel-php` You have to check if you are in the last element. To do that you better should use `for` loop. Or you can put all lines to some array and then merge them with `implode("\n", $linesArray);`

Comment: @hsz, this works fine in IE8. but not in firefox. How can i fix that? :(

Comment: `@shanmugavel-php` Unfortunately that trick does not work with Firefox.

Comment: `@shanmugavel-php` No - you have no way to do this in Firefox. It's just impossible to get it work in `tooltip`. Maybe some custom tooltip engine that will grab text from `tooltip` tag and display it with JavaScript...

Answer (score 0):

The title attribute does not support HTML. You should use `\n\r` or `\n` instead.